# Does Monero have OP codes like bitcoin or similar?

Tags: bitcoin

Does monero have a scripting language with OP codes like bitcoin? OP_RETURN, OP_CHECKSIG etc?

Comment: ahh totally my bad, did not see that :(

Comment: don't worry about it, keep 'em coming :)